# Android app defaults - two handling activities, setting default activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, default

I'm doing something like custom browser with 2 options: View or Download page. Manifest file looks something like this:

```
<activity android:name=".ViewActivity" .... >
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />                
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".DownloadActivity" .... >
    <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />                
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When I open URL I can select what to do. Everything works fine until I select DownloadActivity and confirm with ALWAYS -> it sets app defaults (Open by default). And next time when I click on link, URL is handled by ViewActivity (just because it is first declared in Manifest file - I tried to swap activities in manifest).

Can you help me how to fix it a set the default Activity (not Application) for opening URL? And when I set Download as ALWAYS so it will be always downloading and if I set View as ALWAYS it will be always Viewed. Is it possible? Or is there any other possible solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think it is a limitation of how android stores "default" (by clicking on ALWAYS) and dispatches url to intent filter.

Android stores just which application should be open by clicking on ALWAYS, and not which Activity, because Activities can be renamed, deleted etc. So imagine you as the android system has to lookup how to open `http://foo.com` for an app. You have to look at the in the internal lookup table for the "default" (by clicking on ALWAYS) and then determine that the app with the package `com.example.myapp` should be open.

Now imagine that rather than just the package name of the app you would store the concrete Activity `com.example.myapp.DownloadActivity`. That would be dangerous as hell, because `DownloadActivity` could have been renamed, deleted or even just the intent filter could has been removed from DownloadActivity between setting DownloadActivity as "default" and an update of your app that has introduced that change.

The only thing the android operating system gets notified is when an app has been installed or uninstalled, but not if an activity of an app has been renamed or deleted etc.

Hence is not possible for android to guarantee that it can keep the mapping from `http://foo.com` to `com.example.myapp.DownloadActivity` up to date.

Therefore, Android is just launching the app with package `com.example.myapp` for `http://foo.com and then let the app dispatch it internally to the **first** Intent filter that matches from your apps manifest.

As already said, I'm not 100% sure, but to me it seems reasonable ...

Comment: Yes, it could be a reason, but Android definitely stores the particular Activity . I'm little bit confused just because I followed the logs in logcat and when you set some your activity as preferred Android stores the whole activity (look at example):

`PackageManager: Adding preferred activity com.example/.DownloadActivity for user 0:`

but if you click on link so ViewActivity is started instead of DownloadActivity. It seems to me like a little bug :)
As you mentioned renaming activity, in my opinion to avoid problems is to use activity-aliases